# How can I find if the DataExtensionField is required on an email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

Occasionally we post to send an email and it returns with a message "Missing variable". I'm trying to create some sync ability between what we can validate and send to salesforce. I can query the DataExtension Object and get the DataExtensionField s, but they don't appear to indicate whether the field is required or not. The Email object doesn't have "required fields" or something similar. Is there a field or another object I can get from the SOAP endpoint that will tell me what variables are missing on email templates? I have been working off of [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) so far.